# PHP / Iframe - Google Docs API Viewer and zip files

Tags: php, zip, google-docs-api, viewer

I'm trying to embed the google doc viewer on my site.

Files i need to show are all .zip files containting many file types, doc, images, xml, html etc ..

So the main problem is that embedding a .zip file the google doc viewer lists all the files insisde the zip archive, then when you click one of that files you are redirected to a new browser page tab, where the file is showed.

I, sincerily, would like to avoid the new browser tab redirect, making both actions (click on file, view file) in the same iframe i embed.

this is the code i'm using right now:

```
 <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://mysite.asd.com/test.zip&embedded=true" style="margin:0 auto; width:800px; height:800px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

So i'm answering is there any method to make users able to choose the file on list and view that file in the same iframe i embed?

I'm using PHP, any good solution about that?

thx.